# Cordova access files under www

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to read and return files from www for use in a webserver (this is to open the cordova files via another web browser for use in VR) https://github.com/bykof/cordova-plugin-webserver

I've tried various combinations with the application directory, but what I'm essentially trying to do is something like this

```
  window.webserver.start(8080)
  window.webserver.onRequest(request => {
    if(request.path === '/')
      returnFile('app/index.html', request.requestId)
    else if(request.path.indexOf('static') > -1) {
      returnFile(request.path.replace('/static','app/static'),  request.requestId) 
    }
  })
})
}

function returnFile(file, requestId){

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
window.cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/' + file, fileEntry => 
  fileEntry.file(file => {
    window.webserver.sendResponse(
      requestId,
      {
        path: fileEntry.nativeURL,
        type:file.type,
      }
    )
  })
 )
}
```

I can read the file from within the application, but when I try and serve it I get a file not found error or forbidden error.

How do I get a path to the file that the Java part of the plugin can access?

Any ideas how to go about this?

EDIT

This kind of works

```
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
    window.cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/' + file, fileEntry => 
      fileEntry.file(file => {
        const reader = new FileReader()

        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          window.webserver.sendResponse(
            requestId,
            {
              status: 200,
              body: this.result,
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': file.type,
              },
            }
          )
        }
        reader.readAsText(file)
      })
  )
```

But struggles to send the large javascript files. Any way to read these and send the files as data so the browswer will read them?